# Convert string to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm starting with a text-area string in "HHMM-HHMM\nHHMM\nHHMM" format (hours and minutes). The desired output is an array of objects that key the 1st number to start: and the 2nd to end, like:

```
[
  {
    start: 0900,
    end: 1000
  },
  {
    start: 1200,
    end: 1300
  },
]
```

In the code below I have split the initial string by line so that they will appear as an array:

```
splitting_array = ["0900-1000", "1200-1300"]
```

Next I am trying to use array.map to map each string to a new array of objects mapped to start and end properties. My hangup is here, I can split the 1st and second number using the hypen but I do not know how to do the object property mappings (start: and end:) from there. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
var free_time_hours = document.getElementById('ftid')
  free_time_hours.addEventListener("blur", save_free_time_hours)

function save_free_time_hours () {

  // todo: break the new lines into array elements. Reset each time in case the user input updates

  var splitting_array = free_time_hours.value.split(/\n/)

  // todo: use the map function to map each string to an object with start and end properties

  var split_objects = splitting_array.map(function(str) {
    var box = str.split('-') // box[0] = 1200, box[1] = 1300
    var obj = {}
  // stuck here

  })

  // console.log("objectified start/end values")
  // console.log(split_objects)

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So `String.split` returns an array of your strings split by (and not including) the split-string you pass in, so `box[0]` is your start, and `box[1]` would be your end. Then, you just need to return the object that is to be mapped to your string item.

```js
var splitting_array = ["0900-1000", "1200-1300"];
var split_objects = splitting_array.map(function(str) {
  var box = str.split('-');
  return {start: box[0], end: box[1]}
});
console.log(split_objects); // [{start:"0900", end:"1000"}, {start:"1200", end:"1300"}]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to do Number.parseInt. try:

Comment: @MaxLeizerovich Well, his desired output in the question isn't a real output, sicnce OP has `0900` which would actually be output as `900` obviously. I am simply assuming OP intends to keep those as strings. I can add a comment, sure.

Comment: thats not the output he asked for in the example. If im right try this, if not just ignore :) var splitting_array = ["0900-1000", "1200-1300"];
const pardeRanges = arr => arr.map(item => {
  const range = (item || '').split('-');
  return {
    start: Number.parseInt(range[0]),
    end: Number.parseInt(range[1])
  };
});
console.log(pardeRanges(splitting_array));

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution:

```js
var splitting_array = ["0900-1000", "1200-1300"];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i< splitting_array.length;i++){
   
   var startTime = splitting_array[i].split("-")[0];
   var endTime = splitting_array[i].split("-")[1];
   var obj = {};
   obj["start"] = startTime;
   obj["end"] = endTime;
   result.push(obj);
}

console.log(result);
```